# Update Product Price Programmatically with PHP without Mage

Tags: php, api, magento

I have been searching for a way to update the price of a specific product with PHP without the use of Mage.  I have been trying to use curl to do it, however, when I try it, i receive an error "{"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"product"}". Here's my code:

```
<?php
$productUpdateJson = '{
    "product": {
        "sku": "577617647",
        "price": 324.99,
        "extensionAttributes": {
            "stockItem": {
                "qty": 120,
                "isInStock": true
            }
        }
    },
    "saveOptions": true
}';
$productUpdateJson = json_encode($productUpdateJson);

        $productsJson = http_build_query(json_decode($productUpdateJson));
$ch = curl_init( "http://myserver.com/index.php/rest/V1/products" );

$curlOptions = array(
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "POST",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $productsJson,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( "Content-type: application/json", "Authorization: bearer 1ydds7h1dgb3i1msk1xcvjaacjhr97ht" )
);

curl_setopt_array( $ch, $curlOptions );

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
var_dump($response);
```

Is anyone getting this error and if so, how did you fix it?

Comment: Seems like that fieldName is required and you are not sending it.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the `json_encode` `json_decode` `http_build_query` and just pass your original JSON string to cURL like this:

`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $productUpdateJson`